# Apache Server access log shows another domain's request and got redirected

Tags: apache-2.4, debian-wheezy

I found my apache2 access log (debian) includes some entries not related to my domain and got '301' redirection:

**,-,-,[19/Aug/2014:10:09:54 +0800],"GET /admin.php HTTP/1.0",301,493,,,**
**,-,-,[19/Aug/2014:10:09:55 +0800],"GET /administrator/index.php HTTP/1.0",301,521,,,**
**,-,-,[19/Aug/2014:10:09:55 +0800],"GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.0",301,499,,,**

Obviously those requests are not to my domain, but from this source, debian will default deny all proxy request:
https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration

Besides, I cannot find there is mod_proxy under /etc/apache2/mods-enabled.

I am anxious about:
1. is the server acting as open proxy?
2. why http 301 is returned?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like the typical requests generated by bots scanning random servers for exploitable versions of common software such as WordPress, phpMyAdmin and more.

The only odd thing is, if those files do not exist you would expect a 404 file not found error and not the 301 moved permanently status code.

Do you have mod_rewrite enabled, or an old .htaccess file? E.g. something that redirects requests like ip-address/path to hostname/path? Or a custom ErrorDocument etc.

You're not an open proxy based on those log lines , proxied requests would look like `GET http://remotehost/somepath HTTP/1.0`

Comment: Yes, I enabled the mod_rewrite for some purposes, e.g. deny all access to .txt file except robots.txt. Is this the reason?

Comment: That is the most likely reason. On some of my sites I get similar errors when I redirect all traffic to https. A simple check to see what headers your site returns is `curl -v <ip-address>/wp-login.php` and the same with the correct domain instead of an ip-address.

Comment: After running 'curl', I got 'Moved Permanently' message. Thank you so much!! You helped me a lot, much appreciated!!!